# It is possible to detect if an activity was paused? (thread problem)

Tags: android, multithreading

I have an object which make some http requests in a separate thread to a server. When the response is returned, I call an listener which let my activity know that the operation was finished.

The problem is: if the thread is running and the activity was paused I get `android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@4069ef80 is not valid; is your activity running?` error.

Is it possible to detect if the activity was paused? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Yes see here. Just override the onPause in your activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

Answer (score 5):

Introduce a boolean and update its status when the activity state changes.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
boolean isPaused=false;

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    isPaused = true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    isPaused = false;
    }
```

Use the boolean to determine the activity state.

Comment: Don't forget to call the parent class!  
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        isPaused = true;
    }
Same for onResume

Comment: @OlivierGrenoble Thanks for pointing that out, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: 'welcome. The call to the parent class should be done first. Otherwise I think that you will get an error.

Comment: I believe the variable should be set before calling the parent class. That's what Google is doing [here](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/Activity.java#L7436) for `isDestroyed`.