# Is detecting Video Playing Events possible in android?

Tags: android, media-player, broadcastreceiver

I want to detect events like "Video is playing" "Video has been paused" "Video Play has stopped".

I do not want to write my own player. I just need to log the events of the default video player that has been called. Is there any broadcast event that I can register to for the default player in android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible unless you have a custom rom.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you need, but the answer is "maybe".

Specifically:

[It is possible to detect if an activity was paused? (thread problem)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6169768/it-is-possible-to-detect-if-an-activity-was-paused-thread-problem)

Q: It is possible to detect if an activity was paused?

A: Yes see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html). Just override the onPause in your activity

It *might* be as simple as that.

Alternatively, look at the Media Player state diagram and available methods here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

Comment: I guess I did not state my problem correctly. As I said I do not want to write my own player. I basically want to see when the phone has started playing and paused. For audio I could do it but for video it doesn't broadcast events.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility to bnd to Android's music player service. It is described [here](http://www.alexc.me/android-music-app-service-currently-playing-song/231/). You can obtain the current track and stuff, but I'm not sure whether you can register to events. Let us know if you find out more.

Comment: You need not bind as such, you can register a broadcastreceiver to actions like com.android.music.musicservicecommand but it will give you the events for music only. When I call a video it basically call this "com.android.music.musicservicecommand" intent with a pause command and after taht no events are broadcasted. So I posted this to check if there are any intents that I can register to in addition to the one mentioned